# CRT - non-linear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem

I don't know how to solve system of equations using CRT when there is some quadratic/cubic variable. For example:

> *System 1:*
> $$\boxed{x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}}$$
> $$12x \equiv 9 \pmod{15}$$
>
> *System 2:*
> $$3x \equiv 6 \pmod{9}$$
> $$\boxed{x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}$$
> $$4x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$

I think (please correct me if I'm wrong) the quadratic equation from *System 2* can be rewritten into linear equations as $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{2}$.

How can I rewrite the cubic equation from *System 1* into linear equations to be able to use CRT?

Comment: The cubic is equivalent to the linear congruence $x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. The quadratic in the second list has no solution. (I am assuming you really mean $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.)

Comment: I edited the question, there was an error in the *System 2*. Why do we need to change modulo from 4 to 2 in *System 2*?

Comment: We don't **have to**, but it saves time. the solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ are $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{4}$. So if we stick to $4$  we will have to solve **two** systems of congruences. However, if we collapse $x^2\equiv \pm 1\pmod{4}$ to the equivalent $x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, there is only one system of congruences to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number is congruent to either 0,1 or 2 mod 3. The only option which cubes to 1 mod 3 is 1. Therefore x must be 1 mod 3